# Moment.js change time format character from 'comma' to 'at'

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I get the time in this format `2019-02-06 08:39:11`,
and change with moment.js to `FEB 6TH 2019, 8:39:11 AM` 
the code: `moment(time).format('MMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');`, so I need to change format from `FEB 6TH 2019, 8:39:11 AM` to `FEB 6TH 2019 at 8:39:11 AM`, (change comma with  'at'). Can I do it with moment.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Moment.js documentation

> Escaping characters
>   To escape characters in format strings, you can wrap the characters in square brackets.

```js
const time = "2019-02-06 08:39:11";
const formatted = moment(time).format('MMM Do YYYY [at] h:mm:ss a');

console.log(formatted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```